# Curtain reveal pushing div depending on size of screen

Tags: css

I want to do a similar effect to the curtain reveal, please take a look at: http://dev.ateo.dk/konference-3/

However, depending on the size of the screen, the background of the city at night, will not stay in place. Try and inspect the element, and see how the background is pushed up.

How do i make sure, that the background appears the same on all monitors?

Best regards,
Patrick

Comment: "Curtain reveal" is actually a horribly optimized image that takes ages to load. Look at its size: http://dev.ateo.dk/wp-content/uploads/2013/10/shutterstock_65006059.jpg

Comment: I am not worried about the size, as this is a development site :)

Comment: Well, that gives you that curtain-rolling-down effect. :) I didn't understand it was your site, I thought you wanted to know how it works. So you want the background to scale not according to the screen size, but according to some wrapper element?

Comment: Well, i pretty much just want the background to stay in the same place at all time, so it wont move around according to the monitor size :)